# Possible reasons for Selenium RemoteWebDriver command timeouts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have a number of Selenium tests running 24/7 and a few times a day we are getting random
webdriver timeout exception. For example:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://*.*.*.*:4444/wd/hub/session/4957b6a8-c885-4dd7-98ab-373f35619495/url timed out after 120 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.get_Url()

...
```

Usually it happens in random places (when fetching the current URL, when clicking an element, finding an element, etc.) and in different tests.

RemoteWebDriver's command timeout for HTTP requests is set to 120s and none of the timeouts set with Manage().Timeouts().* exceed 60 seconds.

My question is, what could be the possible reasons for the command timeout?

It looks like Selenium or possibly the ChromeDriver just *locks* occasionally for whatever reason. Although I am unable to verify anything visually since the tests are executed on a headless machine.

Could it be that we overlooked or misunderstood some timeout setting?

Versions:
Selenium v2.42.2, .NET bindings v2.40.0, ChromeDriver 2.10

Comment: Have you read http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/11/net-bindings-whaddaymean-no-response.html, which may hold some insights?

Comment: Thanks JimEvans, that did clarify a few things. 
Luckily the problem seem to have disappeared after updating to 2.43.1 go figure... 
I'll try to debug this further if it decides to resurface again.